# How do I add a field to the list of filterable attributes in Audience Builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, audience, audience-builder

My organization has a new requirement for filtering audiences, however, the field did not exist when we stood up Audience Builder. The field exists in a Synchronized Data Extension that is already referenced in Audience Builder so I feel like it should be pretty straightforward to add this field to the Attribute Library but I can't find any information on how to do that.

Is it possible to do it myself? Or do I have to go through our Marketing Cloud rep to get this added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing your data or use case but your only option to do this without re-engaging the service team is this:

[User-Created Attribute Management](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ab_user_created_attributes.htm&type=5)

> Use this tool to choose data for creating and segmenting audiences. Available data includes raw data or unique values taken from the data model created in Contact Builder for your account. For example, you can use attributes added via this tool to create and segment audiences using stored demographic and purchasing information.